Handling 'Too Large for Available Bit Count' Error When Reading Part of an MP3 File in Python
I am trying to read a specific part of an MP3 file, but I am encountering an error:
[src/libmpg123/layer3.c:INT123_do_layer3():1771] error: part2_3_length (1376) too large for available bit count (760)

The audio file can be accessed here.
My environment is set up using this Docker image: pytorch/pytorch:2.2.0-cuda12.1-cudnn8-devel.
I installed librosa and librosa dependent programs with the following commands:
apt install -y git-lfs ffmpeg unzip libsndfile1
conda install -y -c conda-forge libsndfile
pip install numpy
pip install librosa

I attempted to read the MP3 file with this Python code:
import librosa
audio_array, sr = librosa.load('all.mp3', sr=16_000, duration=5.28, offset=3231.67)

While I can read the entire file using librosa, I am unable to read this specific part of the file. What should I do? Should I ignore this error since I still get the correct NumPy array? What does this error message mean?

Your error message has been cut short. Please edit the question to include the full error. Additionally, there is no link to your MP3 file.

Is it just this one file that you cannot partially read? Or does any other MP3 have the same issue?

I have 5600 audio files with corresponding subtitles, and I want to create parallel data for speech translation. This issue is not unique to this file; many other audio files have similar problems at specific subtitle sections.

I tried to quickly test for you just so we could see if it was system related, but in a new venv I'm getting numpy errors (trying to run v1 code on v2) relating to one of the other imports.

Assuming this is just a warning, ignore it.  You can't just start at an arbitrary location in an MP3 file.  It has to skip until it finds the beginning of a packet.
